# Breeze Todo Example - Why does the TodosController return a string on purge and reset?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze

I'm going over the TODOs example in Breeze for Angular and have a question which I am unable to find an answer for.

Why does the TodosController return a string on both purge and reset?  It doesn't seem to matter if I return any string, null, or nothing at all...

Code snippet:

```
    // ~/breeze/todos/purge
    [HttpPost]
    public string Purge()
    {
        TodoDatabaseInitializer.PurgeDatabase(_contextProvider.Context);
        return "purged";
    }

    // ~/breeze/todos/reset
    [HttpPost]
    public string Reset()
    {
        Purge();
        TodoDatabaseInitializer.SeedDatabase(_contextProvider.Context);
        return "reset";
    }
```

Thanks!
AJ

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it does not matter, in fact thi call has more to do with Entity Framework than breeze. The string is just a message for clarity and can be nice if you are using a tool like [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), which shows your http requests and the information about them. In this case, you would see purged in you http response body in fiddler, so you know the call succeeded. Doesn't look like it's used on the client though.

Comment: You are correct, @mtliesing. The string is just a little feedback. The purge/reset methods exist primarily to support public demos. Don't read too much into them.